# Can I get correct DLL module list for tasklist /m when checking 32 bit program on a 64bit machine?

Tags: dll, cmd, command-prompt, windows-7-x64

Command `tasklist` on windows has really useful feature: it can list all `dll` modules for a process, or all processes. Command bellow will list all DLL files used by `explorer.exe`:

```
tasklist /fi "ImageName eq explorer.exe" /m
```

Looks like this (shortened, translated to english):

```
Process name              PID      Modules
========================= ======== ============================================
explorer.exe                  1104 ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KERNELBASE.dll,
                                   ADVAPI32.dll, msvcrt.dll, sechost.dll,
                                   RPCRT4.dll, GDI32.dll, USER32.dll, LPK.dll,
                                   USP10.dll, SHLWAPI.dll, SHELL32.dll,
                                   ole32.dll, OLEAUT32.dll, EXPLORERFRAME.dll,
                                   DUser.dll, DUI70.dll, IMM32.dll, MSCTF.dll,
```

The problem is that this doesn't work so well for 64-bit processes:

```
C:\>tasklist /fi "ImageName eq firefox.exe" /m

Process name              PID      Modules
========================= ======== ============================================
firefox.exe                   4980 ntdll.dll, wow64.dll, wow64win.dll,
                                   wow64cpu.dll
```

What you see is incomplete, it looks more like this:

[image: image description]

My question then is: Can I start tasklist as 32 bit program or otherwise ensure it will return correct values? I need to call tasklist from another program (Java) and get the list of loaded DLL files. I need this to ensure I do not attempt to load DLL twice.

Comment: Try using the 32-bit version of tasklist.exe from c:\windows\syswow64.  - although since those are 32-bit DLLs, not 64-bit DLLs, you might want to reconsider whether they count or not; hard to say, since I don't understand what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm injecting DLL in application that I know is allways 32 bit. Injecting DLL twice could do nasty things. Therefore I need to check whether DLL was injected already and disable button that triggers the injection.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Tasklist at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\tasklist.exe` prints the same results unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [EnumProcessModulesEx() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to enumerate 32-bit and/or 64-bit modules in the target process.

Comment: I suppose this is a windows function that could be imported in Java JVM through the appropriate dll file.

Comment: Presumably.  I'm not familiar with using Java to calling native APIs.  It might be simpler to implement the API-facing code in a C DLL (or application, though that would be less efficient) and call that from Java.

Comment: @HarryJohnson Will need some work but can be implemented in java using JNA (and supposedly JNI as well). I'll post it here if I succeed and I take this answer as accepted as it proposes more programming approach than running (and bundling) external application.

Comment: I replaced the tasklist command by Win-API calls to EnumProcessModulesEx() [in ruby](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/commit/2ed495710bae637f8985acbce7a02116088d3d14) to fix the issue with 32 bit processes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PowerShell:

```
Get-Process winword| select -ExpandProperty modules|ft -Autosize
```

[Get-process Winword (32bits) on 64bits OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AugcT.png)

Extracted from: https://www.sysadmit.com/2019/07/windows-saber-dll-utiliza-programa.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ListDLLs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx) from [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals)

Example output:

```
F:\>c:\apps\NirSoft\SysinternalsSuite\listdlls firefox

ListDLLs v3.1 - List loaded DLLs
Copyright (C) 1997-2011 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

--------------------------------------------------------------------
firefox.exe pid: 2000
Command line: C:\apps\Firefox\firefox.exe

Base                Size      Path
0x00000000012c0000  0x5f000   C:\apps\Firefox\firefox.exe
0x0000000076d80000  0x1a9000  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00000000748a0000  0x3f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
0x0000000074840000  0x5c000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
0x0000000074830000  0x8000    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
0x00000000012c0000  0x5f000   C:\apps\Firefox\firefox.exe
0x0000000076f60000  0x180000  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x000000006d100000  0x47000   C:\apps\Avast\snxhk.dll
0x0000000074960000  0x110000  C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.dll
0x00000000766d0000  0x47000   C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00000000741d0000  0x62000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\guard32.dll
0x0000000076880000  0x100000  C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x00000000753d0000  0x90000   C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x0000000075110000  0xa000    C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x0000000074b00000  0x9d000   C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x00000000757c0000  0xac000   C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x0000000075720000  0xa0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00000000753b0000  0x19000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x0000000075490000  0xf0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000074900000  0x60000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x00000000748f0000  0xc000    C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x00000000746a0000  0x9000    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\VERSION.dll
0x0000000074c50000  0x5000    C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000074bb0000  0x60000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000074d50000  0xcc000   C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000074600000  0x7000    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fltlib.dll
0x000000006d0c0000  0x1b000   C:\apps\Firefox\mozglue.dll
0x000000006d040000  0x71000   C:\apps\Firefox\MSVCP120.dll
0x0000000067c20000  0xee000   C:\apps\Firefox\MSVCR120.dll
0x0000000060700000  0x1a0000  C:\apps\Firefox\nss3.dll
...
```

---

Source [ListDLLs v3.1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx)

> ListDLLs is a utility that reports the DLLs loaded into processes. You can use it to list all DLLs loaded into all processes, into a specific process, or to list the processes that have a particular DLL loaded. ListDLLs can also display full version information for DLLs, including their digital signature, and can be used to scan processes for unsigned DLLs.

---

**Disclaimer**: I am not affiliated with [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: That would require I bundle this program with my application. I wated something that's present on the windows installation.